# Sharepoint: Is it possible to make subgroups in top navigation menu?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss

I need to make subgroups in the top navigation menu, like:

Home
-Group
--Subgroup

[alt text http://img300.imageshack.us/my.php?image=topnavigationmenudr4.png](http://img300.imageshack.us/my.php?image=topnavigationmenudr4.png)

Is it possible? I can not make more than two levels!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this [blog entry](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/05/15/SharePoint-Tip--How-to-Activate-the-Drop-Down-Menu.aspx) by Heather Solomon.

You need to modify your Master Page to set your **MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels** property of the **SharePoint:AspMenu** tag from 1 to the level you need.

And you will get this as result :

[image: sub sites]
<sub>(source: [heathersolomon.com](http://www.heathersolomon.com/images/postimages/sampledropnav2levels.gif))</sub>